# Allow the user to see the rejection feedback for his/her edit

Tags: feature-request, review, edits

It would help if I could see the feedback when I edit question or answer for other user, so I do not do the same thing again. for example: if I edit an answer and it rejected by the reviewer for the following reason: it will not make the question easier to be understand.

When I open the question link I can see my edit was rejected for the reason I mentioned in the example above, so I can edit other questions or answer with better way in the future.

Comment: You mean clicking on the words rejected edit in this list: http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/37398/ahmad-abuhasna?tab=allactions&sort=suggestions or something else?

Comment: thanks, that view will do, but I hoped for one in the notification menu as will.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to your account in your case that's [Ahmad Abuhasna](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/37398/ahmad-abuhasna) and click on the All Actions tab.

From there select the suggestions sub-tab.

[image: All Actions/Suggestions]

You'll find a list of your recent suggested edits, find the ones that have been rejected and click on the words rejected edit.